# PHP regular expression match 'fill1 pc1' or 'pc1'

Tags: php, regex

In a project we are having so many svg images with the following paths:

Image 1:

```
<path class="fill1 pc1" d="M4276 1802c223,-13 453,84 681,152 21,6 43,12 64,18 21,6 42,11 63,16l264 -799c-27,-20 -54,-40 -83,-60 -492,-345 -1232,-645 -2076,-889 -6,49 -3,59 -20,105 158,101 284,176 388,283 164,166 284,354 371,559 56,131 95,268 153,388 47,97 121,157 195,227z"/>
```

Image 2:

```
 <path class="pc1" d="M4276 1802c223,-13 453,84 681,152 21,6 43,12 64,18 21,6 42,11 63,16l264 -799c-27,-20 -54,-40 -83,-60 -492,-345 -1232,-645 -2076,-889 -6,49 -3,59 -20,105 158,101 284,176 388,283 164,166 284,354 371,559 56,131 95,268 153,388 47,97 121,157 195,227z"/>
```

I can use the following regular expression to match:

```
$svg = preg_replace(
     '/class="fil[0-9]\s+pc1"/',  
    'class="fil${1}\s+pc1" style="fill: rgb('.$r.','.$g.','.$b.');"',
    $svg                  
);
```

The above code will replace the path's class match with **class="fill1 pc1"** this only. some times the "fill1" wont be there. How can i replace this?

Comment: Have you tested whether DOMDocument or SimpleXML can handle SVG?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Im using php's image magic tool to convert svg to png. and i successfully done. For some parts i want to change color where this regex came

Comment: That's indeed really cool.

Comment: `How can i replace this` You can _match_ it by making it optional `class="(?:fil[0-9]\s+)?pc1` ?

Comment: @sln, working really cool, u saved my time https://regex101.com/r/IBXd5v/3

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/IBXd5v/4

Comment: `\s+` in the replacement string is wrong. You probably want to put a single space there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing valid html, then you will enjoy greater reliability by employing a legitimate DOM parser.  I typically endorse DOMDocument with XPath when targeting elements by their attribute(s). Assuming you must target by class, I'll recommend the following:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uFQoo))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//path[contains(@class,"pc1")]') as $svg) {
    $svg->setAttribute('style', "fill: rgb($r,$g,$b)");
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <path class="fill1 pc1" d="M4276 1802c223,-13 453,84 681,152 21,6 43,12 64,18 21,6 42,11 63,16l264 -799c-27,-20 -54,-40 -83,-60 -492,-345 -1232,-645 -2076,-889 -6,49 -3,59 -20,105 158,101 284,176 388,283 164,166 284,354 371,559 56,131 95,268 153,388 47,97 121,157 195,227z" style="fill: rgb(255,255,255)"></path>
    <div>
        hello there
    </div>
    <path class="pc1" d="M4276 1802c223,-13 453,84 681,152 21,6 43,12 64,18 21,6 42,11 63,16l264 -799c-27,-20 -54,-40 -83,-60 -492,-345 -1232,-645 -2076,-889 -6,49 -3,59 -20,105 158,101 284,176 388,283 164,166 284,354 371,559 56,131 95,268 153,388 47,97 121,157 195,227z" style="fill: rgb(255,255,255)"></path>
</div>
```

---

If you don't need to rely more on the classname for targeting, you can more simply target on the element name without XPath.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CnEGq))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('path') as $svg) {
    $svg->setAttribute('style', "fill: rgb($r,$g,$b)");
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
// same output as the previous snippet
```